# NoSuchMethodError in main thread while reading xlsx using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, exception, apache-poi

my code is

```
[...]
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;

public class ExcelRead {

    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        try {

              File excel = new File("Book1.xlsx");
              FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(excel);
              XSSFWorkbook book = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
              XSSFSheet sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator(); 
            while( rows.hasNext() ) {   
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                System.out.println("\n");
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                while( cells.hasNext() ) {

                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                    if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==cell.getCellType())
                    System.out.print( cell.getNumericCellValue()+"     " );
                    else
                    if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==cell.getCellType())
                        System.out.print( cell.getStringCellValue()+"     " );
                    else
                        if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==cell.getCellType())
                        System.out.print( cell.getBooleanCellValue()+"     " );
                        else
                            if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==cell.getCellType())
                                System.out.print( "BLANK     " );
                                else
                            System.out.print("Unknown cell type");
                }
            }
        } catch ( IOException ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the jars that i have added are

- poi-3.9.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.7.jar
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar

the exception is

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory.newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory;

      at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.<clinit>(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:45)
      at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161)
      at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
      at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:37)
      at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:87)
      at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:272)
      at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
      at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:254)
      at com.symplocus.ExcelRead.main(ExcelRead.java:26)
```

Comment: Which java version do you use?

Comment: java standard edition 6

Comment: the code is working fine with jdk7 ........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recent versions of `poi-ooxml` require you to use at least `java 6`. The method in question was only added since `java 6`. Consider upgrading your `java` version.

From the [official docs](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html),

> The OOXML jars require a stax implementation, but **now that Apache POI requires** **Java 6**, that is provided by the JRE and no additional stax jars are required. The OOXML jars used to require DOM4J, but the code has now been changed to use JAXP and no additional dom4j jars are required.

*Emphasis mine.

Since the question was edited, I'm specifying the build this method was [added](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/compat_reports/jdk/1.6.0.17_to_1.6.0.18/src_compat_report.html#Added):

> java 1.6.0_18

So a minimum of this version must be used in OP's case.

Comment: Is your runtime `6` as well?

Comment: That's strange. I still suspect you are running on `java 5` or less. What build of `java 6` are you running on? Just put this line before the line where the error is thrown. `System.out.println(Runtime.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());` and paste the output here.

Comment: You should at least use build 18.
http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/java/compat_reports/jdk/1.6.0.17_to_1.6.0.18/src_compat_report.html

Comment: The patch-level of java 6 likely will not affect this, it is more likely caused by an outdated third party library, probably xml-apis or xerces

Answer (score 1):

This usually indicates that you somehow drag in outdated XML Parser interfaces, e.g. via some transient dependency to an old xml-api version or an outdated xerces jar, which is usually not needed any more at all as Java 6 provides all the XML parsing functionality out of the box.

See [this discusion](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.poi.user/20699) for some more details.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into exactly the same issue as you,
and I found the following jar files have to be used to solve the program:

- poi-bin-3.8.zip
- opencsv-2.3.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.8.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8.jar
- xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar

Newer version will bring trouble.

Comment: I was stuck on this for two hours and this was finally the answer for me.