# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method newFactory()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, xssf

I'm building an Android application and facing a no static method exception when trying to read the **XLSX files**.

Tried all possibilities like updating dependencies in app/build.gradle, but no avail.

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

```
Exception causing line in code: XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);

    08-07 12:37:05.828 16406-16511/droidmentor.tabwithviewpager E/AndroidRuntime: 
    FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: droidmentor.tabwithviewpager, PID: 16406
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method newFactory()Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory; in class Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLEventFactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory' appears in /data/app/droidmentor.tabwithviewpager-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.internal.marshallers.PackagePropertiesMarshaller.<clinit>(PackagePropertiesMarshaller.java:45)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.init(OPCPackage.java:161)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.<init>(OPCPackage.java:141)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.Package.<init>(Package.java:37)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:87)
        at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:272)
        at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
        at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:254)
        at droidmentor.tabwithviewpager.Fragment.ChatFragment$LongOperation.readXLSX(ChatFragment.java:191)
        at droidmentor.tabwithviewpager.Fragment.ChatFragment$LongOperation.doInBackground(ChatFragment.java:112)
        at droidmentor.tabwithviewpager.Fragment.ChatFragment$LongOperation.doInBackground(ChatFragment.java:88)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I'm adding app.gradle file. The other codes are basic XLSX file reading using XSSF. When I tried to run this java snippet in Spring Suite Tool, it runs properly. However, When I integrate those java snippets into the Android app, it causing this runtime exception.

App.Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "droidmentor.tabwithviewpager"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.+'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.10-FINAL'
compile 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.11-beta2'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.11-beta2'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5'
compile 'javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1'
compile 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
compile 'junit:junit:4.7'
compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:2.3'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:3.8'
compile 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:2.3.0'
compile 'dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1'

}
```

Comment: Please add your relevant code as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26866398/nosuchmethoderror-in-main-thread-while-reading-xlsx-using-apache-poi ?

Comment: @Lino, I have tried to update my android project to JDK 1.8 version still, the error has not resolved.

Comment: @VicJordan, I'm adding my app.gradle file for your references. Other codes are basic XSLX file reading using XSSF in JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are applying any obfuscation on your apk, if yes, you need to `-keep` those packages and classes so that they won't be stripped by proguard.

Comment: I haven't applied any obfuscation on apk.